# Noob question rounding half toroid

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, 3d-printing

I have the following shape:

[image: Side View]

[image: Bottom view]

How do I smooth only the curved parts? I would like it so that the bottom of the shape is flat, and it looks like two circles connected by a thin rectangle (instead of two 12-sided polygons right now).

Things I tried:

Subdividing the faces and using a smoothing factor of 1

Result:
[image: result after subdivision]
This works for the most part, but there are two bumps near the bottom of my shape, which I can't seem to get rid of.

2. Shade smooth:

Result:
[image: Shade smooth result]
This also seems to work mostly, but the bottom isn't flat anymore. Plus, there's some weird stuff going on near the bottom again. The bottom also hasn't been smoothed (you can still see the lines from the 12-sided polygon).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do something like this:
[image]

- Use Inset (press <kbd>i</kbd> key when a face is selected, then size it with mouse) to add a second ring to the bottoms. Otherwise we have a 12-gon that will misbehave when we want precise results.
- Add a Subdivision Surface modifier to smooth the model out
- Mark the edges you don't want to deform and increase the "Mean Crease" value to 1, which will reduce the deformation significantly.

First question I've tried to answer, so I hope it was of some help :)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe try this topology? It will work fine with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

[image]